# Selecting a part of a file and copying that into new file in Linux

Tags: linux, text

How can I copy a particular content of a file into a new file using Linux?

For example I have file called test.log file and it contains some 1000 lines. From those 1000 lines I need to copy the lines between 200 - 700 lines.

Is there any single line command in LINUX/UNIX?

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
sed -n '200,700p' logfilename > destinationFilename
```

Comment: Includes 200th line and 700th, 501 lines total. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry to ask it here if it is irrelevant to this question.
What if we want to copy from 200 to end of line?

Comment: @CodeTalker sed matches '$' to the last line, so '200,$p' would work for your needs. Note, the quotes are necessary.

Answer (score 4):

try this line:

```
awk 'NR>700{exit}NR>=200{print $0 > "newfile"}' yourlog
```

the line above will stop processing after line 700. it is helpful if your log file is huge.