# How to select rest of a file excluding some lines in linux?

Tags: linux, text, sed

I need something that does the opposite of the answer(`sed -n '200,700p' logfilename > destinationFilename`) from a similar question ([Selecting a part of a file and copying that into new file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221392/selecting-a-part-of-a-file-and-copying-that-into-new-file-in-linux#15221504)). I need to exclude some lines such as from 200 to 700 and output the rest of the file so I can copy it to another file. How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use 
sed '200,700d' logfilename > destinationFilename

Reference : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-do-i-remove-certain-lines-using-line-numbers-in-a-file